# Create a repository server for Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: redhat

I have one system registered to Red Hat Network. Is it possible to download all the patches and make this registered server as the repository server for all other servers?

I have searched the internet and I have got the command to sync the repository: `reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=channel-id`

Is it safe to do this?

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation needed to create a Red Hat Enterprise Linux repository is located here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016

Keep in mind that you should close this repository to the external world, since it contains binaries from Red Hat Inc. which may be copyrighted.